# Is there any way to fetch web pages in pure perl?

Tags: perl, arm, embedded

I am developing on an old, obsolete embedded ARM computer, and there are no modules available to me for HTTP client support.  No LWP, no HTTP::Tiny, etc.

I can't compile anything for this platform.  The original developers are long gone from the company, and this project is currently in maintenance mode.

Is there any way that I fetch HTTP, and ideally HTTPS, pages using pure perl?  Any modules that I can just copy into the library tree (no CPAN support...)?

Thank you.

EDIT: Failing a perl solution I think I can fall back to running wget or curl from a perl script -- but memory is extremely limited so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: I believe [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny) is pure Perl. You may even have it already; it has been a core module since Perl 5.14 (although it requires non-core modules for SSL).

Comment: What version do you have? What of the core modules do you have?

Comment: What does it mean "just copy?"  No C, OK ... does anything else go?

Comment: I mean just copy the .pm files from the module distribution into my library tree.

Comment: LWP is pure Perl as well, but LWP::Protocol::https has C dependencies. HTTPS support will invariably require a C dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do normal socket programming with no libraries. Perl supports most of the POSIX/c library to do that. Depending on how much of the standard library you have available, your solution will vary. If you have normal sockets like IO::Socket::INET I would recommend HTTP::Tiny, like @ThisSuitIsBlackNot.

Here is a program using just Socket, which should get you started if you need to implement your own HTTP client.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket qw(PF_INET SOCK_STREAM pack_sockaddr_in inet_aton);

socket(my $socket, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die "socket: $!";
my $port = getservbyname "http", "tcp";
connect($socket, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton("www.google.com"))) or die "connect: $!";

send($socket, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n", 0);
send($socket, "Host: www.google.com\r\n", 0);
send($socket, "User-Agent: pureperl\r\n\r\n", 0);

while (my $line = <$socket>)
{
    print $line;
}
```

If you don't have Socket either, you need to get the values for PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM and the two functions done manually.

If you have IO::Socket it is better to use that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    
use IO::Socket;
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => 'www.google.com',
                              PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                              Proto    => 'tcp');
$sock->send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
$sock->send("Host: www.google.com\r\n");
$sock->send("User-Agent: pureperl\r\n");
$sock->send("\r\n");

while (my $line = <$sock>)
{
    print $line;
}
```

But if you have IO::Socket, then Tiny.pm from HTTP::Tiny should load if you just copy it.

I would not recommend trying to solve HTTPS in pure perl, or starting on your own implementation of this.

Comment: `https` is horrible to hand roll. Life is too short for that kind of pain.

Comment: I tried to install HTTP::Tiny, but the make script barfed when it couldn't find CORE/config.h, so I assume it needs to compile something in C.  I should take a closer look at the distribution to confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting the Socket example, I do actually have Socket and IO::Socket available, so this will do me for now (HTTPS can come later).

Comment: @NXT: You should check if you have IO::Socket available to save you some heartache. Also HTTP::Tiny does not require a C compiler, but maybe some of it's requirements does. If you have IO::Socket you should be able to edit the module to work.

Comment: @NXT: You should try to just compy Tiny.pm from HTTP::Tiny and see if that runs.

Comment: @bolav: will look further into HTTP::Tiny this afternoon.  Thanks.

Comment: @bolav: I was able to get HTTP::Tiny to work just by copying the .pm file out into my library directory.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> *Failing a perl solution I think I can fall back to running wget or curl from a perl script -- but memory is extremely limited so I'd like to avoid that if possible.*

That makes no sense, `curl` uses way less memory than LWP.

Loading LWP uses almost 3,000 KiB on my machine. `curl`'s image size is a mere 125 KiB.

Use `curl`.

Comment: I'll admit that part of my objection is that running another process for this is just ugly, plus my intuition is to cut down on process launch overhead.  But I had no idea the difference was so pronounced.

Comment: Those are rough measurements. I didn't actually measure `curl` in-memory footprint, but the difference in scale speaks for itself. // As for the launch overhead, `curl` higher speed should easily make up for it.